# Switch from react-native 0.59.9 to 0.66.0 and native-base in a new instance

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, native-base, react-navigation-v6

Since I had a very dated app, react-native 0.59.9 + native-base 2.10.0, or decided to update it starting from a clean project using the classic:

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

at this point I also installed the new native-base 3.2.1 and I overturned all the files and updated their dependencies, many things were different, especially those related to react-navigation.

Once the dependencies have been resolved, the compilation takes place correctly, as seen from the metro bundler (react-native start) but the application immediately crashes reporting:

```
Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
 ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Comp.displayName')
 ERROR Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
 ERROR Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

I tried to clear the cache, delete node_modules and recreate it but the error always appears.
From what I understand there is some problem with the appRegistry in the early stage, these are my files where I assume something abnormal is happening.

> app.json

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "displayName": "MyApp"
}
```

> index.js

```
import {AppRegistry, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

//Disable the FontScaling set by the device (Component "Text").
Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {};
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;

//Disable the FontScaling set by the device (Component "TextInput").
TextInput.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {};
TextInput.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

> App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Setup from './src/boot/setup.js';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Setup/>
        );
    }
}
```

> ./src/boot/setup.js (here I inserted the NativeBaseProvider component which was not used before.)

```
import React from 'react';
import { NativeBaseProvider } from 'native-base';
import App from '../App.js';

export default class Setup extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <NativeBaseProvider>
          <App />
        </NativeBaseProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

> ./src/App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { createSwitchNavigator } from "@react-navigation/compat";

import Home from './components/Home/homeScreen';
import Login from './components/Login/loginScreen';
import ResetPassword from './components/Login/resetPassword';
import News from './components/News/newsScreen';
import Chat from './components/Chat/chatScreen';
import ProfileIndex from './components/Profile/profileIndex';
import SideBar from './components/sidebar/sidebar';
import NewsDetails from './components/News/newsScreenDetails';
import Privacy from './components/Privacy/privacyScreen';
import SignUpWorker from './components/SignUpWorker/signUpWorker';
import AuthLoadingScreen from './utils/authLoadingScreen';

const SignedInDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Home },
    ProfileIndex: { screen: ProfileIndex },
    Chat: { screen: Chat },
    News: { screen: News },
    NewsDetails: { screen: NewsDetails },
    Privacy: { screen: Privacy },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />,
  }
);

const SignedOutDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Home },
    Login: { screen: Login },
    ResetPassword: { screen: ResetPassword },
    SignUp: { screen: SignUp },
    News: { screen: News },
    NewsDetails: { screen: NewsDetails },
    Privacy: { screen: Privacy },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />,
  }
);

const SignedInStack = createNativeStackNavigator(
  {
    DrawerIn: { screen: SignedInDrawer },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'DrawerIn',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);

const SignedOutStack = createNativeStackNavigator(
  {
    DrawerOut: { screen: SignedOutDrawer },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'DrawerOut',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);

export default createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
        SignedIn: SignedInStack,
        SignedOut: SignedOutStack,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName:'AuthLoading'
    }
);
```

> ./src/utils/authLoadingScreen.js

```
import { View, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, StatusBar, NetInfo } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import React from 'react';

export let globalUserToken;
export let globalNetworkOnline;

// this function is used to set the globalUserToken from other pages
export function setglobalUserToken(newValue: boolean) {
  globalUserToken = newValue;
}

export async function checkNetwork() {
  await NetInfo.getConnectionInfo().then(connectionInfo => {
    if (connectionInfo.type === 'none') {
      globalNetworkOnline = false;
    } else {
      globalNetworkOnline = true;
    }
  });
}

export default class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._bootstrapAsync();
  }

  // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
  _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    globalUserToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token');
    // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
    // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
    this.props.navigation.navigate(globalUserToken ? 'SignedIn' : 'SignedOut');
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
          <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

The problem most likely starts from src/App.js as i have updated the functions for createNativeStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator, createSwitchNavigator which were previously simply StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator, SwitchNavigator from 'react-navigation'.

Or the error resides in ./src/utils/authLoadingScreen.js where it is checked if a login token exists... maybe something has changed here too?

Finally I leave you my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios",
    "build:android": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.9",
    "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.3.20",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.4",
    "@types/react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "native-base": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.16.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.3.0-beta.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.1",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.15.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.2.5",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "jest": "^27.2.5",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Has anyone had this problem or do you know if I have correctly changed the components of react-navigation no longer used in the new version?

Comment: You could just upgrade your existing app using https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/ . This would help you avoid this kind of problems. Then, you can upgrade your libraries while watching for breaking changes (like react-navigation)

Comment: @user3812411 I had already tried in the past but without success ... I'll try again now and I'll update you, thanks in the meantime!

Comment: @user3812411 very difficult, as I remembered, to go from 0.59.9 to 0.66 through the upgrade-helper, also because there is native-base involved ... uff .. I'm trying to fix the new app with the AppRegistry problems ...

Comment: Same issue here. But working in iOS.